# Is possible to send a response from a 'return chain' in Laravel Api without using die()?

Tags: php, laravel, api, response, chain

I have this order **controller**. Its possible to kill the script without using die () and return an response to the user saying that the method picked doesn't exist ? 
Is using die() the right way ?

I have this example here :

```
    public function store(Order $order , Request $request)
    {
        $this->checkcart();
        $this->checkCountry( $request['form']['country'] ); // Can Return a response and kill the script
        $this->checkPayMethod( $request['form']['pay'] ); // Can Return a response and kill the script

        //create order, do calculations if the 3 methods above pass...
    }

    public function checkCountry ( $country ) {
        if ( ! in_array ( $country , country_list () ) ) {
            return $this->doesNotExist();
        }
    }

    public function checkPayMethod ( $pay) {
        if ( ! in_array ( $pay , pay_list () ) ) {
            return $this->doesNotExist();
        }
    }

    public function doesNotExist () {
        //response()->json(['error' => 'doesnot_exist','data' => 'doesnot_exist'] , 403 )->send();
        response()->json(['error' => 'doesnot_exist','data' => 'doesnot_exist'] , 403 )->send();
        die(); //Without Using Die ? 
    }
```

Comment: `return` was created for that. And you can return a response object in laravel like here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work. The script continues. if i use return , the script ll never stop , and the main method store() continues to go on.

Comment: you probably need to refactor the "chain" then, using bools, if some check does not pass you call the return response() object in your "main" method.

Comment: It works with die() but I dont know if its the correct way.

Comment: it is not I prepare an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't return a response object in a sub call if you don't handle it.

A response() object is meant to be returned on the main method that has been called by the router.

I would do that:

Assuming that store is your main method from the router (I assume this because you have the Request object in params)

```
public function store(Order $order , Request $request)
{
    $check = $this->checkcart() && $this->checkCountry( $request['form']['country'] ) && $this->checkPayMethod( $request['form']['pay'] );

    if (!$check) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'doesnot_exist','data' => 'doesnot_exist'] , 403 )->send();
    }

    //create order, do calculations if the 3 methods above pass...
}
```

Make sure then that all your calls are returning boolean (true if check passed and false otherwise)

like this:

```
public function checkCountry ( $country ) {
    return in_array($country , country_list());
}

public function checkPayMethod($pay) {
    return in_array($pay, pay_list());
}
```

Comment: why the binary `|` operator though?